# reset form.fields in antd reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Im using form list from antd with react.js https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.List

I have a simple form list here. I can add and remove fields.

Sometimes I want to **reset** the form **remove items Ive added**.

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
...
<Form form={form} name="control-hooks">
    <Form.List name="fruits">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
            <>
                {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => (
                    <Row key={key}>
                        <Col span={24}>
                            <Form.Item {...restField} name={[name, 'color']}>
                                <Select placeholder="Select fruit">{
                                    fruits.map((fruit, index) =>
                                        <Option key={index} value={fruit.color}>
                                            {fruit.color}
                                        </Option>
                                    )
                                }
                                </Select>
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item {...restField} name={[name, 'quantity']} initialValue={1}>
                                <InputNumber placeholder="Quantity" />
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Button onClick={() => remove(name)}>Remove</Button>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                ))}
                <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()}>
                        Add
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </>
        )}
    </Form.List>
</Form>
...
<Button type="primary" onClick={resetForm}>Reset from outside</Button>
```

This is my try:

```
const resetForm = () => {
  form.resetFields();
}
```

Any ideas how I can make it? Thank you

**Edit:**
I added more detailed explanation
[image]

**Edit2**

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-robinson-6q577?file=/src/index.js

I tried to make a example and for some reason it worked .... what is the difference???

**Edit3**

Solution:

I found the problem! It was the initialValue. If I have initialValue in any of my Form.Item, antd will not remove those dynamically added fields. Thanks for the help

Comment: I think resetFields, resets it to the initialValues. And what are you trying to do, are tyring to change some other fields, after resetting the form?

Comment: I am not sure about the use of the List in there, https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-18-5-forked-tq4ze?file=/index.js
I have done a dynamic form without list, forked from one of the samples in antd, when you click reset it removes an input, and when all are gone, brings them all back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values provided as the initialValues should be used by the reset function.

```
<Form
 ...
        initialValues={{first_name: 'John'}}
/>
```

If you want to change some of them afterwards the way to go is;

```
form.setFieldsValue({ first_name: 'John' });
```

to do that your fields should have the name properties defined here.

```
<Form.Item
  name="first_name"
```

Comment: Hey @hazimdikenli, thanks for the answer. It was almost the answer that I needed. I think my question was too ambiguous so I edited it. Could you check it one more time, please? Thanks a lot

Comment: The form is generated by the entries in the formFields list, so what you need to do is to manipulate your formFields variable, you should clear the entries from there. If you already have this in a state variable then the question is why it is not working. If you have not done that already, You should put those in a state variable, like
const [fields, setFormFields] = React.useState(formFields);
and on reset button, clear the entries in the form fields, then rendering should take care of the rest, by the way you should be using fields variable to render the form. I hope this helps.

Comment: The fields are getting reset with no problem (Its values are being reset). The problem is that these fields remains on the screen. What I'm trying to do is to remove these dynamically added fields.

Answer (score 1):

Antd `Form.List` component provides a way to add the same fields again in the form dynamically.  The children of the component is expecting to be used as function of a child just like `render prop`. So, this render function is going to be invoked by antd `Form.List` component. We don't have controlled over the invocation of the function of a child.

The type of children of `Form.List` is given below. I have taken from [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/24458eb54e01d5ed86224dbf3cfc025af622a092/components/form/FormList.tsx#L24).

```
export interface FormListFieldData {
  name: number;
  key: number;
}

export interface FormListOperation {
  add: (defaultValue?: StoreValue, insertIndex?: number) => void;
  remove: (index: number | number[]) => void;
  move: (from: number, to: number) => void;
}

export interface FormListProps {
 // other types
 children: (
    fields: FormListFieldData[],
    operation: FormListOperation,
    meta: { errors: React.ReactNode[]; warnings: React.ReactNode[] },
  ) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

So, we can use the fields, operation and meta data in the children function.

---

Your below snippet, doesn't do that Antd Form.List is expected to do. You're not calling a children function, its Antd Form.List component who is going to call the children function with some defined props that is mentioned in the above type snippet.

```
 const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([]); // you don't need any state.
 ...
 <Form.List>
     {formFields => (  // error, it should be fields that antd expects
       <div>
          {formFields.map(formField => (
          <Form.Item {...formField}>
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
        ))}
      </div>
     )}
  </Form.List>
```

Basic example of Form.List with reset and no inputs is hidden below, please unhide to be visible:

```js
// don't run it, it just to hide long snippets
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Form, Input, Button, Space } from 'antd';
import {  PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const Demo = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form:', values);
    
  };

  const onReset = () => {
    form.resetFields()
  }

  return (
    <Form form={form} name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="hello">
        {(fields, { add }) => (
          <>
            {fields.map(({ key, name,  }) => (
              <Space key={key} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="baseline">
                <Form.Item
                 
                  name={[name, 'first']}
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing first name' }]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                 
                  name={[name, 'last']}
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing last name' }]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                </Form.Item>
              </Space>
            ))}
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                Add field
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Form.List>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
        <Button type="secondary" onClick={onReset}>
          Reset
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
// dont run it
```

`form.resetFields()` will clear the input values and remove the inputs from the form if the `Form.list` has a name property/attribute associated with it.

Comment: @Ricardinho you don't need a state for form fields.

Comment: Yes, you might be right. form.resetFields() does not work for me =/

Comment: Reset button should be inside form element. It is semantically not right to have reset button outside the form to reset all the form control elements in a form.

Comment: `render function` and [`render prop`](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)  are two different thing in react but it has one thing common that is the function that we provide as a render function or render prop are going to be called/invoked in some other component like here antd Form.List children was calling your function.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
form.setFieldsValue({ fruits:[] });
```

Comment: Got this error:  Uncaught TypeError: nameList.map is not a function
    at Object.FormStore.resetFields